# How to concatenate two lines quickly in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

The basic operation is, imagine I have two lines of python codes in the opening buffer

```
    datacontour(set_color=set_color, figout="test",
            figext="pdf")
```

the second line is indented by 8 spaces because it is a continuation of the first line, now I want to combine both lines together, eliminating the spaces between the two

```
    datacontour(set_color=set_color, figout="test", figext="pdf")
```

What is the easiest way to do this? or what kind of shortcut I should define in the vimrc file? Thanks.

Comment: See `:help J`, `:help gJ`, `:help :j`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Press J from the line 'dataContour...'

The next line will be merged to the current line.

Answer (score 2):

Type "J" (capital J) while your cursor is on the first of the two lines.

Comment: duh, I just found that I have this in my evernote, so stupid to forget such an easy action. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Type J on the first line.
hope it helps